# Textarea placeholder and change value

Tags: jquery, textarea

I have probably found a bug in jQuery with textarea value.

I have a textarea with a placeholder:

```
<textarea cols=​"20" id=​"Message" name=​"Message" rows=​"2" style=​"width:​500px;​" 
placeholder="Ecrire une note...">​</textarea>​
```

When I load the content with $.ajax, I set the value with 
`$('#Message').val(data.Message);` but nothing appears. I have tried with .val(), .html(), .text(), .append() but ever same behavior, the value is well set in source code but not displayed. If I remove the placeholder, same code is working well.

So, do I remove the placeholder on textarea and manage it with jQuery, or something exist to have a placeholder and set value possible without trick ?

Comment: When this statement gets executed $('#Message').val(data.Message)

Comment: Ever time I change the value of a dropdownlist, I populate the textarea with a $.ajax().done(). The textarea is visible when the proccess is fired.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://jsbin.com/ruzaliwo/1/edit?html,js,output). Why are you so sure that it's someone else's bug?

Comment: I think you have bug in your ajax success or done function...check that data.message contain valid data

Comment: I can reproduce the bug from the Chrome console with string parameters

Comment: And the return data is well valid. {"Success":true,"Message":"foo","Id":35}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the format of data.Message? The following statement works though.

```
 $('#Message').val("Works");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/ATJgg/

Comment: Right, it's working with a setTimeout too :/ But not working on my application

Comment: Can you see in the console what data you see in data.Message

Comment: Yes => {"Success":true,"Message":"foo","Id":35}

Comment: Queer. Can you also see the type? I used your message herr. http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/ATJgg/1/.

Answer (score 0):

> I have probably found a bug in jQuery with textarea value.

You're a bit pretencious lol.

Anyway, do you have your code inside the basic

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
// Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

???

Answer (score 0):

You should use **value** attribute instead of placeholder. Then get it's text using `$('#Message').val()`

Comment: I don't have the same color text between placeholder and value. So I can, but I'll do make a trick to have the same color too.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is my fault :/

The container with dropdownlist and textarea was created 2 times, the result goes in the 1st container except the 2nd was visible...

Sorry to bothered you.

Comment: So, not a jQuery bug after all? ;-P

Comment: Damnit no, just a bit pretencious ^^